# WinAPI заблокировать вход пользователя

Tags: windows, winapi

Добрый день.

Есть такая ситуация: имеется некоторая служба, которая запускается при загрузке компьютера и, при необходимости, выполняет некоторые действия. Необходимо чтобы пока эти действия выполняются никакой пользователь не мог войти в систему, т.к. запущенные приложения могут помешать работе службы.

Вопрос: есть ли какая-нибудь возможность отложить появление выбора пользователей, например как это делает Windows Update ('Подождите идёт настройка системы')?..

**Добавлено:** Windows 7, обычный вход, не терминал, не в домене. Т.к. служба написана мной, то ищу решение через WinAPI типа: заблокировал - изменил что нужно - разблокировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как это делает Windows Update

Можно и так. Там ограниченный набор действий, если вам достаточно, то вполне можно использовать. Почитайте о *Primitive Operations Queue Executor*

Есть ещё вариант вклиниться в процесс загрузки через [BootExecute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963230.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) но там только Native API. Хорошо и с примерами про эту методику можно [почитать здесь](http://hex.pp.ua/bootexecute.php). Во всех остальных случаях придётся "толкаться локтями" с другими процессами.

Comment: Посмотрел, спасибо. Не то что мне нужно, но, видимо, других способов это сделать нет (gina.dll не в счёт).

Comment: На самом деле можно ещё попробовать `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell` подменять на заглушку, отображающую пользователю сообщение, что загрузка задерживается. Но не уверен как оперативно применится изменение этой ветки реестра.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](https://serverfault.com/questions/327202/denying-allowing-remote-desktop-users-in-windows-2008-server-r2) предлагают в реестре настройку поменять

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\TSServerDrainMode
0 = Allow all connections
1 = Allow reconnections, but prevent new logon until reboot
2 = Allow reconnections, but prevent new logon
```

P.S Я подозреваю, что если служба повиснет и не вернет состояние реестра назад, то тебе придется править это не через RDP, так как сервер скорее всего будет отвергать подключения, а идти к серверу и править.

Можно еще сделать батник, который будет кикать пользователей, повесить в расписание с периодичностью 10 сек.

Еще, как альтернатива, можно при входе пользователя открывать какой-то блокнот с сообщением, что идет обслуживание.

Comment: Нет, нет, windows - клиентский, семёрка, вход не через терминал, а обычный.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё такой "костыль" с локальной политикой, запрещающей вход группе и наполнением этой группы: https://241931348f64b1d1.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/how-to-temporary-disable-interactive-logon-on-windows/